# Issue understanding an aspect of data allocation and unsigned ints

Tags: c, malloc, spell-checking, cs50, unsigned-integer

I have an assignment asking me to write a spell-checker by implementing a few functions into some given code. I am unable to compile due to some syntax errors.

First is:

```
speller.c:291:19: error: comparison of array 'trav_ptr->word' not equal to a null
      pointer is always true [-Werror,-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (trav_ptr->word!=NULL)
```

and:

```
speller.c:293:13: error: cannot increment value of type 'unsigned int (void)'
        size++;
```

from this function:

```
void count(trie *root_ptr)
{
    trie *trav_ptr = root_ptr;
    if (trav_ptr->word!=NULL)
    {
        size++;
    }
    for (int n = 0; n<26; n++)
    {
        if (trav_ptr->paths[n]!=NULL)
        {
            trav_ptr=trav_ptr->paths[n];
            count(trav_ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe my issue lies in understanding how malloc works. When mallocing memory for a struct trie

```
typedef struct trie
{
    char word[MAXCHAR];
    struct trie *paths[26];
}
trie;
```

Is the char field of my struct not NULL? Since I have not filled it with anything yet.

As for the other error, I believe that I cannot increment unsigned int size (declared globally) because I did not initialize it, but I am unsure if initializing it will mess up the code provided to me.

Here is the whole program:

```
/**
 * Implements a spell-checker.
 */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

#undef calculate
#undef getrusage
#define MAXCHAR 45
// default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

typedef struct trie
{
    char word[MAXCHAR];
    struct trie *paths[26];
}
trie;

double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

#define LENGTH 45

bool check(const char *word, trie *root_ptr);

bool load(const char *dictionary, trie *root_ptr);

unsigned int size(trie *root_ptr);

bool unload(void);

void count (trie *root_ptr);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: speller [dictionary] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // structs for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // determine dictionary to use
    char* dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // load dictionary
    trie *root = NULL;
    trie *root_ptr = root;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary, root_ptr);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // abort if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(text, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH+1];

    // spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
    {
        // allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // we must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // update counter
            words++;

            // check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word, root_ptr);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(fp))
    {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // close text
    fclose(fp);

    // determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size(root_ptr);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
     time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // that's all folks
    return 0;
}



/**
 * Returns number of seconds between b and a.
 */
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                 (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                 (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
bool check(const char *word, trie *root_ptr)
{
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    for(int j = 0; word[j]!='\0'; j++)
    {
        str[j]=word[j];
    }
    trie *trav_ptr = root_ptr;
    for(int i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (trav_ptr->paths[str[i] - 'a']==NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            trav_ptr=trav_ptr->paths[str[i] - 'a'];
        }
    }
    if (str==trav_ptr->word)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char *dictionary, trie *root_ptr)
{
    FILE *file_ptr;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    file_ptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file_ptr == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    trie *trav_ptr = root_ptr;
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, file_ptr) != NULL)
    {
        for(int i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            if (trav_ptr->paths[str[i] - 'a']==NULL)
            {
                trie *next_trie = malloc(sizeof(trie));
                trav_ptr->paths[str[i]-'a'] = next_trie;
                trav_ptr = next_trie;
            }
            else
            {
                trav_ptr=trav_ptr->paths[str[i] - 'a'];
            }
        }
        strcpy(trav_ptr->word, str);
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
void count(trie *root_ptr)
 {
    trie *trav_ptr = root_ptr;
    if (trav_ptr->word!=NULL)
    {
        size++;
    }
    for (int n = 0; n<26; n++)
    {
        if (trav_ptr->paths[n]!=NULL)
        {
            trav_ptr=trav_ptr->paths[n];
            count(trav_ptr);
        }
    }
}
unsigned int size(trie *root_ptr)
{
    count(root_ptr);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}
```

Comment: > "Is the char field of my struct not NULL? Since I have not filled it with anything yet."  Malloc does not fill memory with zeroes or anything else. It does nothing but ensure that some area of memory is safe for you to use, and gives it to you. If you want zeros in it, put them there yourself, or use `calloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s consider the expression `trav_ptr->word`. The `->` operator says to do two things: Use the structure that `trav_ptr` points to, and refer to the member in it named `word`. First, in order for this to work, `trav_ptr` must be pointing to a valid allocated structure. Then, the resulting expression **is** the member `word`.

Next, `word` is a `char` array. In most expressions, when an array is referred to, it is automatically converted to the address of the first element of the array.

So this is why the compiler is warning you about comparing `trav_ptr->word` to NULL. It can never be null; it **must** always be the address of the first element of `word` in a structure that `trav_ptr` points to.

Possibly, you intended to compare `trav_ptr` to NULL. `trav_ptr` is just a pointer, not an array or a structure member. It can point to a structure, or it can be NULL. So, when you get a value for `trav_ptr`, you want to check whether it points to a structure or contains NULL.

Regarding `size`, you declared it with `unsigned int size(trie *root_ptr);`. This makes it a function that takes a `trie *` argument and returns an `unsigned int`. It is a function that you call, not an object that you can increment.

Comment: In essence, an array cannot be NULL and a function cannot be incremented.